# Glue Crawler creating a separate table for each csv file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-glue

I am copying csv files from source  s3 bucket to destination s3 bucket. Once the files are in the destination bucket we have a glue crawler that populates the data in redshift. For some reason the crawler is creating a table for each csv file. I made sure all the files have headers, same no of columns and datatypes, but still I am getting the issue.
Is there anything I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried enabling Create a single schema for each S3 path as in https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/glue-crawler-multiple-tables/